# Error occurred while installation of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I code,
import tensorflow as tf
the following error occurs:

```
 File "C:\Users\liuyuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\tensorflow.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Comment: Please review this and update your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask currently without any code example, project reference or further explanation this question is no good.

Comment: Thank you! I am a newer and I'll do that.